# Автотесты, как избавиться от firstrun страницы в Mozilla

Tags: java, firefox, test-automation

При запуске Mozilla

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

открывается страница - https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/48.0.2/firstrun/learnmore/. После чего автотесты дальше не проходят.

Как можно обойти эту проблему?

**Обновление**

```
static protected WebDriver driver;

System.out.println ("Before Mozilla");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //();
System.out.println ("After Mozilla");
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: После открытия окна браузера я разумеется хочу перейти на какой-то определённый адрес. Теперь из-за этой страницы - не могу. Не проходит автотест дальше.

Comment: Тест написан на java. Не знаю, что можно ещё добавить.

Comment: Например, код теста и как вы его запускаете, а также основные параметры окружения. В текущем виде, с большой вероятностью, вам никто не сможет помочь, так как совершенно не ясно, что у вас происходит.

Comment: И вот контрольное - After Mozilla - я уже не вижу.
А браузер открыт на странице firstrun.

Comment: Запускаю в Eclipse посредством TestNG